# Cannot find the table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using SQLite for the  first time in android and is stuck with this exception
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: employees (code 1)`. I donot know how to solve this. Can anyone please help.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Activity {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myemployeedatabase";

    TextView textViewViewEmployees;
    EditText editTextName, editTextSalary;
    Spinner spinnerDepartment;

    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewViewEmployees = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewViewEmployees);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextSalary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSalary);
        spinnerDepartment = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDepartment);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonAddEmployee).setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewViewEmployees.setOnClickListener(this);

        //creating a database
        mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }
@Override
public void createEmployeeTable() {
        mDatabase.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (\n" +
                        "    id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
                        "    name varchar(200) NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    department varchar(200) NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    joiningdate datetime NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    salary double NOT NULL\n" +
                        ");"
        );
    }
    //this method will validate the name and salary
    //dept does not need validation as it is a spinner and it cannot be empty
    private boolean inputsAreCorrect(String name, String salary) {
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            editTextName.setError("Please enter a name");
            editTextName.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }

        if (salary.isEmpty() || Integer.parseInt(salary) <= 0) {
            editTextSalary.setError("Please enter salary");
            editTextSalary.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //In this method we will do the create operation
    private void addEmployee() {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String salary = editTextSalary.getText().toString().trim();
        String dept = spinnerDepartment.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //getting the current time for joining date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String joiningDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        //validating the inptus
        if (inputsAreCorrect(name, salary)) {

            String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO employees \n" +
                    "(name, department, joiningdate, salary)\n" +
                    "VALUES \n" +
                    "(?, ?, ?, ?);";

            //using the same method execsql for inserting values
            //this time it has two parameters
            //first is the sql string and second is the parameters that is to be binded with the query
            mDatabase.execSQL(insertSQL, new String[]{name, dept, joiningDate, salary});

            Toast.makeText(this, "Employee Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonAddEmployee:

                addEmployee();

                break;
            case R.id.textViewViewEmployees:

                startActivity(new Intent(this, EmployeeActivity.class));

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

logcat

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: employees (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO employees 
                                                                             (name, department, joiningdate, salary)
                                                                             VALUES 
                                                                             (?, ?, ?, ?);
                                                                             #################################################################
                                                                             Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                             Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                                                                                (no such table: employees (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO employees 
                                                                             (name, department, joiningdate, salary)
                                                                             VALUES 
                                                                             (?, ?, ?, ?);)
```

`DBHelper`

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myemployeedatabase";

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ EmployeesEntity.TABLE_NAME+" ("
                    + EmployeesEntity.id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + EmployeesEntity.name  +" TEXT,"
                    + EmployeesEntity.department  +" TEXT,"
                    + EmployeesEntity.joiningdate  +" INTEGER,"
                    + EmployeesEntity.salary  +" REAL);");
        }
        private class EmployeesEntity implements BaseColumns {
            public static final String TABLE_NAME = "employees ";

            public static final String id  = "id";
            public static final String name  = "name";
            public static final String department  = "department";
            public static final String joiningdate   = "joiningdate ";
            public static final String salary   = "salary ";
        }
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
            // to simply to discard the data and start over

            onCreate(db);
        }
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you newer use `createEmployeeTable` method, and `employees` table is not created.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to create employee table inside this.@VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: by calling the `createEmployeeTable` method

Comment: where you are invoking the method createEmployeeTable()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you create the database as per `mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);` you then click the `TextView` which triggers the `onClickListener` which invokes the `addEmployee` method which invokes the SQLiteDatabase `insert` method. At this stage the database is empty as you have not created the table.

You have two simple options to fix the issue :-

#### Option 1

The first is to invoke the `createEmployeeTable()` e.g. add the line

```
        //creating a database
        mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        createEmployeeTable(); //<<<< ADDED
```

#### Option 2

The second is to utilise the DBHelper that you have written. To do it this way:-

1. Add a class variable for the DBHelper (say after `SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;`) e.g.

   ```
   DBHelper mDBHlpr;
   ```
2. Instead of :-

   ```
       //creating a database
       mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   ```

   - have :-

     ```
     //creating a database
     mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
     mDatabase = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase();
     ```
   - Note. This second method will require that the database is deleted (see below) as the DBHelper's `onCreate` method will only be invoked when the database is created.

I'd suggest the second option is preferable (the `createEmployeeTable()` method can then be deleted).

I'd also suggest deleting the Apps data or Uninstalling the App (to delete the existing database)

- **Note** the above code is in-principle code and hasn't been tested and may contain typing errors.

Comment: Thankyou so much sir@Mike T... I tried the second option and its working

Answer (score 0):

try to put `compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'` on your gradle so you can see your database on `chrome://inspect` if created or not

also, try to create database and table by creating a new class.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 // Database Information
public static final String DB_NAME = "DATABASE_NAME";

// database version
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;


 //<editor-fold desc="CREATE_KMPost_TABLE QUERY">
private static final String CREATE_KMPost_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + KM_Post + "("
        + KMPost_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + ROUTE_NAME + " VARCHAR,"
        + PLACE + " VARCHAR,"
        + POST + " INTEGER,"
        + PRICE + " DOUBLE,"
        + DISCOUNTED_PRICE + " DOUBLE,"
        + PRICE2 + " DOUBLE,"
        + DISCOUNTED_PRICE2 + " DOUBLE,"
        + PRICE3 + " DOUBLE,"
        + DISCOUNTED_PRICE3 + " DOUBLE)";
//</editor-fold>

 public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_KMPost_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: this won't solve the problem as there is no `employees` table, as the error says.

Comment: well then, he need to try `com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0` to make sure if his db was created

Comment: I don't think that he *needs* that. There are much easier ways to debug application.

Answer (score 0):

ok I guess Your problem in creating your database

You are Dealing With SQlite No  MYSQL or SQLSERVER

so you can try it

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ EmployeesEntity.TABLE_NAME+" ("
                + EmployeesEntity.id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + EmployeesEntity.name  +" TEXT,"
                + EmployeesEntity.department  +" TEXT,"
                + EmployeesEntity.joiningdate  +" INTEGER,"
                + EmployeesEntity.salary  +" REAL);");
```

and add this class

```
  private class EmployeesEntity implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "employees ";

        public static final String id  = "id";
        public static final String name  = "name";
        public static final String department  = "department";
        public static final String joiningdate   = "joiningdate ";
        public static final String salary   = "salary ";
    }
```

and you can now easily make Your Query without worries about names

**Update**

you are using datetime as String ..  it`s better to use it as Long Variable

as i did in SQL strutcre

so  in your Insert Query Dont Put DateTime as String You can Get it as long here

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    values.put(Time,calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Sorry for asking this sir as I am new I cannot follow u..Should I add this along with my code? or modify it. Can u please help@Elsunhoty

Comment: ok Look , in class DbHelper in Function onCreate  you put my code 
db.execSQL .....   then you create inner class  EmployeesEntity 
in DbHelper   OK

Comment: I have created a new class as above. But still getting the same error in logcat@Elsunhoty

Comment: what about try to delete app from phone First and try Again

Comment: Tried that now.Getting same error in logcat and application crashes@Elsunhoty

Comment: Thanks for the help sir@Elsunhoty

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class instead to handle the work for you. It will provide you methods where you can do the necessary work required.

You can see a sample [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html#java) as provided by Android trainings.

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```